# router.navigate is not working (Angular6, lazy loading)

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm a newbie for Angular 4+ (currently using v.6). I've been trying to use **this.router.navigate(['/landing'])** function to redirect from login component to landing component, it's not working properly.
It will show the landing page for a sec then redirect back to login page again.

But if I try to navigate through a normal link, for example,

```html
<a routerLink="/landing">landing</a>
```

It work properly.

Here is my app-routing.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'landing',
    loadChildren: './landing/landing.module#LandingModule'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'landing',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'landing',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And here is the code in the login component,

```js
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  login(){
    this.router.navigate(['/landing']);
  }
  
}
```

Here is the code in landing-routing.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LandingComponent } from './landing.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'', component: LandingComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LandingRoutingModule { }
```

Thanks for helps.

Comment: Do you have any guards?

Comment: @David No, I don't. This is a clean project just created.

Comment: Try this  ,in landing-routing.module.ts ,  `path:'landing', component: LandingComponent`

Comment: In the login html component are you sure that you don't have a `href="#"` where you are calling `login()` ?

Comment: can you share proxy.conf here ?
what could also happen is your proxy.conf might be loading a diff main.js for the re-direct and your local code would not be in action.

Answer (score 7):

I faced similar issue, how I resolved it:

In Component.ts

```
constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute){}

this.router.navigate(['../landing'], {relativeTo: this.route})
```

try this and let me know if it helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

try change this:

```
{
  path: 'login',
  loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'
}
```

to this:

```
{
  path: 'login',
  loadChildren: () => LoginModule
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But my best solution is this:

add to constructor:

```
constructor(private readonly loader: NgModuleFactoryLoader)
```

then only after loading module itself you should call navigate:

```
 this.loader.load(./login/login.module#LoginModule)
                .then(factory => {
                    this.router.navigate(['/landing']);
                });
```